# Rename of S3 file in versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of files in S3 with enabled versioning and have a scenario like below

Suppose I have renamed `test.pdf` to `testrename.pdf`. What S3 does is:

1. creates `testrename.pdf` (means copies the `test.pdf` to `testrename.pdf`)
2. delete the `test.pdf` and also creates `test.pdf` with delete marker

How can I get the original file of `testrename.pdf` (from which object file it is changed)?

In this case, I need to get the details of `test.pdf` as it is the original object.

Comment: There is no tool or option for that provided by AWS. You have to develop fully custom solution for that.

Comment: thank you Marcin, could you suggest? I see possible option is lambda function.  how can I get the original object of the file with lambda code?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the original object"? If `test.pdf` has been deleted, then you cannot 'get' it.

Comment: if we enable versioning, can get the deleted objects or files in s3.   I wanted to know the original file name/details of renamed object

Comment: Turn on cloudtrail data logs for your S3 bucket and see what operations actually happen when you rename.  The data in those operations is your best bet.  But I don't think there's an actual API call for copying s3 objects, just creating new ones; if that's true, you won't find anything in the log about where the data in `testrename.pdf` came from.